# Accessing object from HTML?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

```
myObject { div: htmlElement, foo1: bar1, foo2: bar2 }
```

Key `div` is *original* key and it contains the `HTML` of this object.

Is it possible to access/get/set `myObject` and other values: `foo1` and `foo2` when I have `htmlElement` in scope, *e.g* clicked it?

`myObject` is prototype and I wouldn't mind making prototype getter/setter but I don't know how to access object with/through `HTML` element.

---

**Making an object:** don't mind *Google Maps part*, it's just a normal object..

```
function customHTML(latlng, foo, map) {
    this.latlng = latlng;
    this.foo = foo;
    this.setMap(map);   
}
customHTML.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

customHTML.prototype.draw = function() {
    var self = this;
    var div = this.div;

    //Create div if there's none
    if (!div) {

        div = this.div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'custom-html';

        var panes = this.getPanes();
        panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
    }

    //Location on map - not relevant for this question
    var point = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng);
    if (point) {
        div.style.left = (point.x - 20) + 'px';
        div.style.top = (point.y - 64) + 'px';
    }
};

//Create new objects
var data = /*parsed JSON*/;
var count = data.lenght;
var myMap = /*Google Map object - not relevant for this question*/;

for(i=0; i<count; i++) {
    new CustomHTML(data[i].latlng, data[i].foo, myMap);
}
```

**Somewhere else in the code:**

```
//Clicking element that was made above
jQuery('body').on('click', '.custom-html', function(event) {

      //I need to access customHTML.foo for example, how?
      //PS! I need to access it from outside, I cannot 
      //attach this click event in prototype.draw
}
```

Comment: `myObject` is JSON right?

Comment: @pratikwebdev Data is taken from JSON but I construct my own prototype `myObject`, this is just an object in browser's memory that I need to access through `HTML` *(on click event to be precise)* that is rendered in viewport and is part of that object.

Comment: @Juhana Why not? HTML element in String format? Further on rendering this string can be used to render element?

Comment: so `myObject` is JSON as well. If you could fetch it out of browser memory or from anywhere you can access it in HTML element when in scope. Provide more information on when and where you need to access it.

Comment: @pratikwebdev No, it's not JSON, I parse JSON before getting data from there and constucting my own object. I added an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign `new CustomHTML(data.latlng, data.foo, myMap);` to JS variable.

```
 var customEle = new CustomHTML(data.latlng, data.foo, myMap);
```

You can access it as

```
 jQuery('body').on('click', '.custom-html', function(event) {
   alert(customEle.foo);
 }
```

**UPDATE** To answer your second question on multiple elements.

1) Assign ID to `div` being created in `draw` function.

2) Create a structure in JSON to hold all `customHTML` by `id` as key.

```
var arrCustomHTML = {};
arrCustomHTML.divId = customHTML;
```

3) How to retrieve it.

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.custom-html', function(event) {

       var divId = $(this).prop('id');
       var customHTMLForDiv = arrCustomHTML.divId;
       alert(customHTMLForDiv.foo);
 }
```

There is another way as well. To append `customHTML` for that `div` during creation using jquery `data()` function after you create that element.

```
  div.data('customHTML' , customHTML);
```

To access it on event:

```
   jQuery('body').on('click', '.custom-html', function(event) {
       var ele = $(this).data('customHTML');
       alert(ele.foo);
  }
```

Lmk if it works for you

Comment: This is a great idea however what if there are multiple `CustomHTML`? How do I access the right object of this particular `HTML` element that is part of that object?

Comment: Updated my answer. @Solo

Comment: Thanks, Im sure it will work. I had using `id` or `data-` attribute in my mind but I thought that maybe there's an easier way to get that object _a.k.a_ get the parent property of that `HTML` element _a.k.a_ move up in object's hierarchy and use prototype getters and setters.

Comment: AFIK That is not possible since `div` is being stored in `customHTML` object but once it is rendered it can not be coupled with JSON object itself. Please accept and upvote if it solves your problem